# Entity Framework and AsQueryable performance issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, async-await

when using profiler to truck the time the following code, I find it takes about 1 sec.

```
using (var dbConnection = new DBName())
{    
    var results = dbConnection.SomeTable.AsQueryable().Where(x =>x.ActiveFlag);
    return await results.ToListAsync(); 
}
```

The sql query which is being created by this code doesn't take long, but i see that the following line is:

```
var results = dbConnection.SomeTable.AsQueryable().Where(x =>x.IsActive);
```

What can cause this performance issue?

Comment: 1. If Entity Framework schema is large, it could take some time to build schema internally. If you repeat same call, would it be faster than first one?
2. How big table is? It might take some time to load all data into memory you have table with 1M+ records.

Comment: @pakeha_by thanks for replying, i'm calling this code 5 time the most and the schema is really little (10-30 rows the most)

Comment: IIRC, `AsQueryable` loads the entire table of the database (this can be short with only a few records but will take longer and longer), can't you directly `Where` on `SomeTable`?

Comment: Also, AsQueryable does create and execute the query (but so do other methods), but because you haven't specified anything the query ends up looking like something along the line of `SELECT * FROM SomeTable;` see how that could be problematic/ not best practice?

Comment: How long does `dbConnection.SomeTable.AsQueryable().Where(x =>x.IsActive);` take? How long does `dbConnection.SomeTable.Where(x =>x.IsActive).ToList();` take?

Comment: @mjwills I'm checking it and let you know

Comment: "but i see that the following line is" - what does this mean? Can you re-write more clearly?

Comment: Any luck @israelaltar?

Comment: Nope....... :-(